# Understanding the loss function in Yolo v1 research paper

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, yolo

I'm not able to understand the following piece of text from YOLO v1 research paper:

*"We use sum-squared error because it is easy to optimize,
however it does not perfectly align with our goal of
maximizing average precision. It weights localization error
equally with classification error which may not be ideal.
Also, in every image many grid cells do not contain any
object. This pushes the “confidence” scores of those cells
towards zero, often overpowering the gradient from cells
that do contain objects. This can lead to model instability,
causing training to diverge early on.
To remedy this, we increase the loss from bounding box
coordinate predictions and decrease the loss from confidence
predictions for boxes that don’t contain objects. We
use two parameters, lambda(coord) and lambda(noobj) to accomplish this. We
set lambda(coord) = 5 and lambda(noobj) = .5"*

What is the meaning of "overpowering" in the first paragraph and why would we decrease the loss from confidence prediction(must it not be already low especially for boxes that don't contain any object) and increase that from bounding box predictions ?

Answer (score 2):

There are cells that contain objects and that do not. Model often very confident about the absence (confidence around zero) of the object in the grid cell, it make gradient from those cells be much greater than the gradient from cells that do contain objects but not with huge confidence, it overpowers them (i.e around 0.7-0.8). 
So that we want to consider classification score less important because they are not very "fair", to implement this we make weight for coords prediction greater than for classification.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand your point regarding "fairness" of scores but I still am not able to get why will the gradients be higher for the cells that do not contain objects. It will be pretty helpful if you can elaborate on this point concerning the gradients.